# Event Bubbling issue with a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-bubbling

I have this Event bubbling problem in jQuery.
I found some solutions but doesn't work for a 'select' tag.
So my parent tag is a accordion topbar that triggers content inside.
The problem I have is that I need a dropdown menu in that bar on the right side.

I tried the event.stopPropagation(); but no luck.

```
<ul class="accordion" data-accordion>

  <li class="accordion-navigation">
      <a href="#comp1">Title

        <div class="deelcompetentiescoreBox">
          <span class="label"><i>A</i></span>
           <select class="deelcompetentieDropDown" onchange="javascript:assigndelibscore()">
            <option value="7" >AA</option>
            <option value="8" selected="selected">A</option>
            <option value="9">B</option>
            <option value="10">C</option>
          </select>
        </div>

      </a>

    <div id="comp1" class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have a screenshot here
https://www.evernote.com/l/AAJPx_N0H75E4LzG5ZuwE4Gu-DVBK-nJojE

Anybody that sees a solution.

Many Thanks.
Harold.

Comment: Better post js code together

Comment: a problem fiddle would be much appreciated to work on with

Comment: Could you make a fiddle please !

Comment: which jquery accordion plugin you are using?

Comment: sorry guys, I was offline for a few days… My problem is solved by Max. Appreciate your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<select id="mySelection" class="deelcompetentieDropDown">
```

Javascript part

```
 document.getElementById('mySelection').addEventListener('change', assigndelibscore);
```

dont forget to add the parameter `e` in your `assigndelibscore` function:

```
 var assigndelibscore = function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Max. You are the MAX ;)

Comment: I know. It's awsome. I love it.